# How to Bypass Safari Autoplay Block

Tags: javascript, html, web, safari, media-player

I am developing a site which one of it's core features is playing music. It works flawlessly on any browser except for Safari. After hours of investigation I discovered a setting in Safari, preventing websites from auto playing media.

Once I disabled this feature (so I allowed auto playing media) the music was being played on Safari flawlessly too.

I now need to discover a way to bypass the auto playing media block Safari has implemented as it's default setting. I tried googling around but any problem like mine has remained unanswered, at least from what I found.

I know this is possible to fix because so many popular sites (i.e. Netflix, Youtube, Soundcloud, Spotify, etc.) all work perfectly on Safari.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: are you using video tags ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera I am using an audio tag.

Comment: no....its just like over riding the default properties of chrome & mozilla.... just like you cant make [download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute work for IE10 & lower...same is for safari.. do an exception handling rather

Comment: Any success in finding a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

That's a new feature implemented for user convenience and comfort in Safari 11. While it's more about stopping sites from auto-playing ads in the middle of a library or interrupting the user's music, it would definitely get in the way of sites like yours too.

I would suggest not attempting to bypass it, because you probably *can't*. Instead, detect if your visitors are using Safari, and display a contextual popup explaining to them how they can enable auto-playing media on your site. This leaves your users in full control of their browsing experience.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed reply: I definitely would've done that already, though literally 99% of the site requires auto play so I'd at least like to spend some time trying to resolve the issue before opting into doing the method that doesn't even let users view the website before doing something that we ask. Are you sure there's not a solution? If so how are all these big websites doing it?

Comment: How Youtube passes these features? Safari has Website preferences with three Auto-Play options: Allow All Auto-Play, Stop Media with Sound and Never Auto-Play. Youtube's default setting is Allow All Auto-Play. How Youtube achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

yeah it would be better not to block the default of safari as said by jono..and rather detect on your website if the incoming request if from a safari browser using

```
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));
```

or

```
function GetBrowser()
{
    return  navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "safari";
}
var isSafari = GetBrowser();
```

> if (isSafari  == true )
>   //do your alternative thing

Comment: Is there a way then to check for the safari version too (as its 11+ that blocks auto play). Or even better see if they have the setting enabled?

Comment: you can check which websites support audio tag in the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

Comment: **console.log(window.navigator)** will give you all the info like browser name **appName** , version **appVersion** etc

Comment: Still curious though; how do sites like Netflix and Spotify override the autoplay block?

Comment: yeah,,,the trick is safari & chrome do not allow some actions until user's input action is received..so the bind the audio auto play with an user input like.. onlclick or onswipe .... here is an [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#N100D5)

Comment: So how does say Spotify do it? Because you click one button and for hours you might not click another as it keeps playing songs in your playlist.

Comment: yeah...they do some hacks like binding the autoplay to pageload event.. or may be something like **webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;**

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all audio files you want to play are loaded before a user interaction, such as a click or tap.

I am using Howler.js, and I can stop the current audio and play the next with one click.

Using Howler.js as an example, I declare my audio variables in a file.

```
 const currentAudio = new Howl({src: ['audio1.mp3']})
 const nextAudio = new Howl({src: ['audio2.mp3']})
```

In the file where I will play the audio, I will import/pass the variables above and call this function onClick while currentAudio is playing.

```
const playAudio = ()=>{
 currentAudio.stop();
 nextAudio.play();
}
```

If I were to declare the variables within the playAudio function, this would not work in Safari.